# Searching fields by many time of OR operand in ORM?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I need to find a records where the values of some field are different, it looks like `IN`, better to say `FIND ALL WHERE field=1 OR field=2... OR field=9`
And these OR can be a lot. Is it possible to make somethig with this in ORM on Kohana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORM::factory('Model')->where('field1', '=', 'value')->or_where('field2', '=', 'value')...
```

Comment: maybe it must look like ``ORM::factory('Model')->where('field','IN',$arr)->find_all();`` but I don't know exactly, maybe it's a wrong example. Sure if ``$arr = ( 2, 3, 5, 8 );``

Comment: Victor, please put your answer into it's own answer for proper credit.  Your solution is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I might misunderstood the question. If you simply want to query multiple values for ONE field, you are much better off with a `field IN (1,2,3)` query.